# ¿Cómo Consultar una duplicidad de dos campos en una tabla?

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla 'db_productos2 de una empresa, el cual tiene aproximadamente 15 atributos. Dentro de estos estan "Clase, tipo y sub tipo". 
La tabla tiene 16.500 registros, algunos desordenados, repetidos o mal rellenados ya que fue creciendo desde el año 2010 donde los sistemas no estaban muy desarrollados.

**El punto es que necesito conocer la cantidad de registros que se repitieron en dicha tabla.**

**Por ejemplo:** 
En el atributo "Tipo" Zapato, aparecen 200 veces y en el atributo "Sub Tipo", "Zapato" vuelve a aparece 300 veces. Se necesita el total de todos los productos repetidos ...En este caso 200 zapatos repetidos en ambas tablas.

Comment: La pregunta es confusa, ¿podrías explicarte mejor?

Comment: Hola amigo Bienvenido, podrias coloccar el query que usas para verificar el error que tienes

Comment: @CriticalGhost mas abajo publique la respuesta que logre armar de a poco. Me parecia muy rato no encontrar nada al respecto. Serias tan amable de comentar tu opinion?

Comment: La pregunta empieza hablando de una tabla y termina diciendo **ambas tablas**. En algún momento me perdí

Answer (score 0):

Me pase dos dias buscando la solucion y solo encontraba la utilizacion de inner join, group by, having, etc. Para resolver este problema se debe recurrir a la utilizacion de cuatro vistas primero para obtener una tabla virtual a donde realizar consultas posteriores y **no sobre la misma tabla**, para luego general las dos consultas siguientes :

```
   `create or replace view vista_subtipo as SELECT count(*) as cantidad, subtipo  FROM db_productos  group by subtipo;

    create or replace view vista_tipo as SELECT count(*) as cantidad, tipo  FROM db_productos  group by tipo;

    create or replace view vista_clase as SELECT count(*) as clase, clase  FROM db_productos  group by clase;`
```

Luego con las vistas podemos comparar por ejemplo la tabla tipo con sub tipo y obtener los minimos duplicados de todos los registros, utilizando las sentencias **Inner join y least.** y si es util, crear la nueva vista

```
`create or replace view vista_minDup as select tt.cantidad,tt.tipo, ts.cantidad, ts.subtipo, least(tt.cantidad, ts.cantidad) as minimo 
from vista_tipo as tt inner join vista_subtipo as ts on tt.tipo = ts.subtipo;`
```

Esperando poder ayudar a quien lo necesita, cualquier modificación o mejora no dude en comentar. Saludos

Comment: _La tabla tiene 16.500 registros, algunos desordenados, repetidos o mal rellenados ya que fue creciendo desde el año 2010 donde los sistemas no estaban muy desarrollados._ Si el problema es lo que planteas en la pregunta, **no te hagas la ilusión de haberlo resuelto creando vistas.** Las vistas son maneras de ver, a veces falsas, la realidad. Aunque en este caso la _veas_ bien, los datos siguen estando mal, o sea, duplicados. La solución debe pasar entonces por determinar cuáles datos están duplicados para eliminarlos, o incluso por cambiar la forma en que está organizada la BD.

Comment: Buen punta, @A.Cedano

Answer (score 0):

El criterio para decir que dos registros son duplicados es algo dificil de determinar y debes considerar ciertas reglas, y una vez evaluadas volver a considerar esas reglas.

Una básica sería considerar el caso en que los tres campos valen lo mismo

```
select campo1, campo2, campo3
from table group by campo1, campo2, campo3
having count(*) > 1
```

El segundo aspecto que debes seguir es el de la normalización de los valores. Si estos han procedido de diferentes fuentes y de varios usuarios, no todos tienen el mismo sentido de la ortografía

```
select distinct(campo1) as valor from table
union
select distinct(campo2) as valor from table
union
select distinct(campo3) as valor from table
order by valor
```

ahora verás todos los valores ordenados alfabéticamente y te será fácil agruparlos

Para cada grupo debes considerar un valor de referencia. En el caso que puedas actualizar los valores podrás hacerlo y si no usa tablas auxiliares

En este punto puedes hacer la agrupación

```
select campo1, campo2, campo3
from table group by campo1, campo2, campo3
having count(*) > 1
```

y puede ser que vuelvas a tener valores repetidos

A partid de ahora puedes convertir el valor de cada columna en un númerico, con MD5, por ejemplo. Luego suma todos los valores de un mismo registro. De esta forma, esos registros que tengan el mismo valor, signficara que tiene los mismos valores en diferentes columnas, pero en otro orden

Espero que estos tres algoritmos te sirvan por ahora. Cualquier duda la comentamos con placer.

Atentamente,